# MM/PB(GB)SA calculations for DESMOND trajectories

Tags: software-recommendation, gromacs

I did molecular dynamic simulations with DESMOND.

Now, I want to obtain the interaction free energy using MM/PB(GB)SA.

The free tools I found to perform such calculations are [AmberTools](https://ambermd.org/AmberTools.php) and [g_mmpbsa](http://rashmikumari.github.io/g_mmpbsa/).
AmberTools work only on Amber-type files, whereas g_mmbbsa works with GROMACS-type. This imply that I have to convert the DESMOND trajectories to AMBER or GROMACS formats.

I did that using VMD. In case of AMBER, I got the files *prmtop* and *mdcrd* whereas for GROMACS I got *gro* and *top* files. I also tried to use [InterMol](https://github.com/shirtsgroup/InterMol), but I am getting an error on conversions.

For both tools, I need to prepare the input files. In case of AmberTools, there is a Python script (ante-MMPBSA) that extract the solvated complex, the complex, the ligand and the receptor from the trajectory files. This scrip is falling to do that from the converted trajectories. In case of g_mmpbsa, it also need the index.ndx file.

My question: **Is there a way to accomplish this task?** Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Try here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. There's way more VMD questions there, plus there's an entire tag just for GROMACS, and AMBER is on topic there too.

Comment: Hi @user1271772 (or I must said @Nick? This is Camps, lol.